# Shallow copy question in javascript object

Tags: javascript

```js
const girl = {
  name: 'Anna',
  info: { age: 20, number: 123 }
};

const newGirl = { ...girl };
newGirl.info.age = 30;
console.log(girl.info.age, newGirl.info.age);
```

The output is 30 30, we copy the properties of the girl object into the newGirl object using the spread operator. This operator creates a shallow copy of the object. Shallow copies are not safe from mutations.

Lets see another example

```js
function test(obj) {
  const output = { ...obj };
  output.age = 30;
  return output;
}

let person = { age: 10 }
let newPerson = test(person);
console.log(newPerson.age, person.age); // output is 30 10
```

As you can see the second example also use a spread operator to create a copy of the object. Why does it do not behave the same as the first example? Why it does not affect original object field data?

Comment: That's what shallow copy means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Javascript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the first snippet you're modifying the nested object in the `info` property, while in the second snippet you're modifying the containing object.

When you make a shallow copy, `girl` and `newGirl` are different objects, but they both contain references to the same `info` object. So `girl.info` and `newGirl.info` are the same objects, and modifying the properties of one of them will be reflected by accessing the other.

But if you assign to `girl.name` or `newGirl.name` you're modifying properties of different objects. You wouldn't see the change in the other object. This is what you were doing by assigning to `output.age` in the second snippet.

A deep copy would copy all the objects that are referenced recursively, not just the top-level object. If you made a deep copy, no modifications at any level would be seen when accessing the other object.

Answer (score 2):

The only values in `person` are immutable primitives (`10`). There are no objects that would be copied by reference (unlike `girl` where `info` is an object).

Answer (score 2):

You've changed two things in your second example:

- Passed the object into and out of a function
- Changed the structure of the object

The difference you're seeing has nothing to do with the extra indirection through a function, only the structure of the object.

Let's change one thing at a time and see what happens:

```js
const girl = { age: 20, number: 123 };

const newGirl = { ...girl };
newGirl.age = 30;
console.log(girl.age, newGirl.age);
```

Output: `20 30` - the original object has *not* been modified, because we directly copied the **scalar** value `age`, so the two properties are completely separate.

```js
function test(obj) {
  const output = { ...obj };
  output.info.age = 30;
  return output;
}

let person = { info: { age: 10 } }
let newPerson = test(person);
console.log(newPerson.info.age, person.info.age);
```

Output is `30 30` - the original object *has* been modified, because we only copied the *object reference* for the `info` property, so both properties hold references pointing at the same object.